# How does the Linq to SQL works?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I use Linq to SQL in my project. I fetch data from a SQL Stored procedure using it. It works perfectly, but I dont understand exactly how does LINQ SQL communicates with SQL server internally, where does it stores the data after fetching it? From where it gets the connection string?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx, basically an implementation of [`IQueryable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) does the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better to read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx